# SwingWorker thread not close even the task is finished?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I have a swingworker in my java project.
I use netbean "profiler" to monitor the thread.
I don't know why the swingworker thread still exist in the monitor of the profiler in NetBeans and it is in "Wait" State. In other words, if i click button b 10 times, there are 10 swingworker threads!
Thank You.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    final JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    f.setSize(400, 400);
    b = new JButton("B1");      
    f.add(b,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {           
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           new SwingWorker() {

                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();
        }
    });

    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't dispose"? That it's not GC'd? If so, I don't think that we can fully control this.  Can you post a very small compilable ,runnable sample program that demonstrates the problem, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: I don't know why the Thread is still in wait state, but I do believe that you can have no more than 10 threads in the SwingWorker thread pool. Perhaps the Threads are just sitting in the Pool waiting to be used again when needed (or perhaps better say, "wading in the pool"? ;)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, check out the output from this modification of your code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo002 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      f.setSize(400, 400);
      JButton b = new JButton("B1");
      f.add(b, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new SwingWorker() {

               @Override
               protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                  Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
                  System.out.printf("ID: %d, Name: %s%n", current.getId(), current.getName());
                  System.out.println("Active Count: " + Thread.activeCount());
                  return null;
               }
            }.execute();
         }
      });

      f.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: exactly, as per my comments to your original question. That is the size of the SwingWorker thread pool.

Answer (score 2):

not, that isn't `SwingWorker` or something similair, please read [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html), how to construct and use `SwingWorker` correctly, check what's happedns if isn't there method done() or missed referrence to `Future<?>` (copied from tutorial) `SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<ImageIcon[], Void>()`